# Child classes not inheriting properties from parent class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, parent-child

This isn't working the way I thought it would. Here are my classes:

```
class App {
    public $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

class Analysis extends App {

    public $analysis_id;

    public function __construct($analysis_id) {
        $this->analysis_id = $analysis_id;
    }
}

class Standard extends Analysis {

    public function __construct($analysis_id) {
        parent::__construct($analysis_id);
    }
}
```

`$db` is my database (mysqli) object that I've passed to the App class.

When I try to perform a new Standard Analysis, I initiate it like this:

```
$analysis = new Standard($analysis_id);
```

The Analysis class contains methods that retrieve meta data about an analysis, while the Standard class contains methods that retrieve calculations for that specific type of analysis. I thought I would be able to access the `$db` object, but I can't from the Analysis or Standard class. Do I need to pass the `$db` object to the Standard class when I initiate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Analysis` class needs to call the constructor on its parent, `App`. This doesn't happen by default. Because `$db` is a parameter of the `App` constructor, you will have to pass this in from the subclasses as well, and then call  `parent::__construct($db)` from the `Analysis` constructor.

Correct code:

```
class App {
    public $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

class Analysis extends App {
    public $analysis_id;

    public function __construct($analysis_id, $db) {
        $this->analysis_id = $analysis_id;
        parent::__construct($db);
    }
}

class Standard extends Analysis {
    public function __construct($analysis_id, $db) {
        parent::__construct($analysis_id, $db);
    }
}

$analysis = new Standard($analysis_id, $db);
```

Comment: So I just need to include `parent::__construct();` in my `__construct()` function in the Analysis class then?

Comment: @Jeff - you need to pass in `$db` as well, since this is a parameter of the `App` constructor.

Comment: Ah okay. I see what you did in the example. So I guess if I were to ever extend my Standard class, I would just have to pass those same parameters to it, then use a `parent::__construct()` within the new extended class to initiate the Standard class, and so on. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Each *object* is independent of each other object. Just because you instantiated an `App` object somewhere does not mean that anything else has access to the data in that object, whether the classes are related or not. The `$db` argument you pass into an instance of `App` is available in that object and only in that object.

Inheritance inherits the *object structure*, not data.

```
$app1 = new App($db);
$app2 = new App($db2); // <- different app instance, different data
$app3 = new App;       // <- does not have access to $db
$std  = new Standard;  // <- also does not have access to anything in $app1
```